# Function Mappings

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

There are two “shift functions” mapping $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb N$: $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=\max\{0,n-1\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

How to show that $(g\circ f)(n)=n$ for all $n$, but that $(f\circ g)(n)=n$ does not hold for all $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then:
$$(f\circ g)(n)=g(f(n))=g(n+1)=\max\{0,n\}=n,$$
because $n>0$.

On the other hand (we asumpt that $0\in \mathbb{N}$) we have:
$$(f\circ g)(0)=f(g(0))=f(0)=1\neq 0$$
Of course if $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3...\}$, then:
$$(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})((f\circ g)(n)=n)$$

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the definitions closely, and you can find your answers.

1. Recall that $(g\circ f)(n)=g(f(n))$. Since $f(n)=n+1$ we have that $f(n)>0$ for all $n$. Therefore $f(n)-1\geq 0$. I'll leave you with finishing this part of the proof.
2. In the above hides the answer to the second question as well. Note that $f(n)>0$. So $f(g(n))$ cannot be equal which number?

Answer (score 0):

$g\circ f (n)=g(f(n))$ and by definition of $f$, you have
$g\circ f (n)=g(f(n))=g(n+1)$ and by definition of $g$,
$g\circ f (n)=g(f(n))=g(n+1)=\max \{0, (n+1)-1\}=\max \{0, n\}=n$, because $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}$ .
But now you see that
$f\circ g (n)=f(g(n))= f(\max \{0, n-1\})$, so for $n>1$ you have
$f\circ g(n)=f(\max \{0, n-1\})=n-1\neq n$.